# NGINX as TLS-transparent (secure TCP) and a TLS-terminating (TLS offload) reverse-proxy based on sub-domain name

Tags: ssl, nginx, https, tls, reverse-proxy

I host a few services from my home network to the internet and I learned recently about reverse-proxy concepts using NGINX. Some of my services (like Home Assistant) have the built-in ability to enable and manage TLS via let's encrypt, other services I host are unsecured HTTP (like Nextcloud). Because of this I'd like to configure NGINX to handle each of them like this:

1. no TLS-termination on Home Assistant - HA handles the TLS certs (#4 TLS-Passthrough reverse-proxy) - End-to-end encryption
2. TLS-termination on Nextcloud - NGINX handles the TLS certs (#3 TLS-Offloading reverse-proxy) - Unencrypted transmission within my local network

[#3 and #4 examples from this reference: OPNsense docs](https://docs.opnsense.org/manual/reverse_proxy.html)

I know that NGINX can terminate TLS and I have it configured that way now -- seems to work well (using the `http {}` directive). I've read a few articles on configuring NGINX to not terminate TLS (using the `stream {}` directive [[NGINX docs](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/securing-tcp-traffic-upstream/), [Stackoverflow question about SSL passthrough](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40135151/2612293)]).

I've been searching around looking for someone who has implemented both of these strategies simultaneously, but I'm coming up empty handed. I'm also having a hard time figuring out the NGINX syntax. If someone could share an example config file of such an implementation so I can see how it should work that would be excellent! :)

Thank you!